# Preventing program from closing

Tags: c#, wcf

I am writing a WCF named pipe server. I have something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using(var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(XServer), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")))
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IXServer), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "XServer");
            host.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

After hitting `host.Open();` the program stops working. This program is supposed to be a server, so it has to run all the time. How do I do it? Do I need to add `while(true)` loop after `host.Open()`? Because that solution looks lame to me.

Comment: Depends on your architecture. Are you hosting this as console app ? windows application (winform/WPF), Windows service, IIS ? Is this application suppose to do other activities or just running the service and do the behavior ? i mean i assume it must be non blocking call. so if you do while true, your thread will block..

Comment: In addition, What is the .Net version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you'd do something like this:-

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    using(var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(XServer), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")))
    {
      host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IXServer), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "XServer");
      host.Open();
      create an exit event
      while (true)
      {
        begin asynchronous read
        wait on asynchronous read or exit event <- puts thread to sleep
        if event was exit event, break out of while loop
        parse read data
      }
      destroy exit event
    }
  }
}
```

The exit event gives you a way to cleanly terminate the process and the use of events lets the OS reduce the amount of CPU time your program consumes whilst wait for data to arrive.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic thing you could do (blocking!) is:

```
class Program
{
     private static ManualResetEventSlim _manualResetEventSlim;
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        using(var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(XServer), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")))
        {
          host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IXServer), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "XServer");
          host.Open();      
          _manualResetEventSlim.Wait(); //This will **block** the application thread, But its not supposed to block your WCF Service host thread. 
        }
}
```

}

Do not forget to .set the event on Dispose()..